# Complex number to exponential form

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

How do you transform $\Re(1-z)$ to exponential form (Euler)

Also, how do you transform $|z-1|$ to exponential form?

Comment: I do mean to do it in that form, but I dont quite understand your explanation though

Comment: $\theta$ is the angle between the real axis and the vector $(a,b)$ corresponding to a complex number $a+bi$. The parameter $r$ in $re^{i\theta}$ is exactly the norm of the complex number, so $r=\sqrt(a^2+b^2)$. So if the complex number is real (i.e. $b=0$) $\theta$ is $0$ and $r=|a|$.

Comment: So, if I'm looking for the real part of the complex number 1-z the answer should be  r=1-z and the angle is 0, so I just have cos of theta?

Comment: No. The real part of $Re(1-z)$ is $a=Re(1-z)$ and the imaginary part of it is $0$, because the real part is real. Therefore $r=|Re(1-z)|$ and $\theta=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by transforming these to exponential form?  Do you mean to write these numbers themselves in exponential form, or to describe how to compute them from the exponential form of $z$?  (The former is rather trivial, since they are real numbers.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $z = x+iy$, its exponential form comes from identifying it as the point $(x,y)$ in the (Argand) plane. This basically amounts to writing it in what would be polar form in the real plane. Writing it as $$z = re^{i\theta}$$. If you graph the point $(x,y)$ and treat it as a vector its easy to see that $r = |z|$ and $\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$.

For purely real numbers, they are already in exponential form since they are equal to their modulus and $\theta = 0$.

Also, you can write $$Re(z) = \frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$$

$\\$

if you want to write it purely in terms of z. Both of your numbers are purely real and thus they are already in exponential form. I suppose if you wanted to be strict about it you could write it as $$|1-z| = |1-z|e^{0i}$$